# Modern Mathematica vs Wolfram One: Where are they going

Tags: discussion

I've been working with Mathematica Online now for a number of years and have been very happy with it. Now as a volunteer for a data science for social good project its performance is falling a bit short of what we need for the data analysis component (specifically the online notebook `GeoGraphics` function has been a headache and delaying deliverables).

Now I'm thinking I've outgrown the online version and should upgrade. Searching just brought up [an old thread on the Wolfram community forums about the differences](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1081329?p_p_auth=z528KSW4), which makes sense to me, I'm just wondering where the organization is headed? I'm comfortable with Mathematica but happy to switch over to the newer platform if that's where their focus is. It's a bit of a subjective question but is the consensus here to go with Wolfram One? Does the company slowly want to get everyone on that platform? I don't have a strong opinion either way, and both are priced the same for the individual level on the site.

If anyone has any information on this please let me know.